# Querstion regarding Url with Hebrew latters field validation in .net core entity frame work 5

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, url, entity-framework-core, hebrew

I have asp.net core 5.0 solution with Entity Framework Core 5 and in my model I have  two fields which contains url string.

my problem is how to validated them as they might include Hebrew latters.

the regular [Url] field attribute doesn't match a url with hebrew latters and therefor raise a validation error to the user.

I tried also custom Regular Expression attribute like this:

[RegularExpression(@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~]*)?$",ErrorMessage ="Please enter a valid url!")]

And it still not accepts Hebrew latters in the url string.

I must say that making the same matching check with a regular Regular Expression like the following, does work correctly.

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~]*)?$");
bool isMatch = rgx.IsMatch("http://www.msomesite.net/תנאי קדם ודרישות הקורס.doc");

Does someone has an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can try to change your parttern in RegularExpression like this:

```
@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~\0590-\05FF]*)?$"
```

Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ValidationModel
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~\0590-\05FF]*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid url!")]
    
        public string Url { get; set; }
       
    }
```

View：

```
@model ValidationModel
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Url" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Url" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Url" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you want to use it in both Regex and RegularExpression attribute,try to use:

```
@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~\u0590-\u05fe]*)?$"
```

Result:
[image]

test with `http://po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc`:
[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. secondly I tried it but it's not working i received the following error message: RegexParseException: Invalid pattern '^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~\0590-\05FF]*)?$' at offset 61. [x-y] range in reverse order.

Comment: `  [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~\0590-\05FF]*)?$",ErrorMessage ="Please enter a valid url")]
        [Display(Name ="Source Url")]
        public string RequestUrl { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^((http|https|ftp)://)([\w-]+\.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?%&,=~]*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid url")]
        [Display(Name = "Target Url")]
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }  `

Comment: Did you use `\0590-\05FF` in `Regex rgx = new Regex(...)`,it can only be used in RegularExpression attribute,if you want to use it in regex,you can refer to my updated answer and use `\u0590-\u05fe` to replace `\0590-\05FF`.

Comment: Nop I used it in a RegularExpression attribute as I wrote above, also I tried on several online .net regex validator and all of them gave me the same error. if I add the u it does not raising the error but when i try7 to check a url like http://po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc it parse it like it's a valid url where it actually not valid url

Comment: You mean you use `\u0590-\u05fe`,it don't have the error.But it will get valid when it is actually invalid?

Comment: When i used '\u0590-\u05fe', if i try "http://po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc" it should be invalid but it says its valid

Comment: I think you'd better try it in your local project.I have updated the result in my local project,it can work.

Comment: Have you use `<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>` and `<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Url" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Url" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Url" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>` in my view?

Comment: I have the _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml with the <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: Did you have `<span asp-validation-for="Url" class="text-danger"></span>` and bind with input name?Only with it can show validation error in view.

Comment: @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RequestUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RequestUrl" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="RequestUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

Comment: Did you use it in your local project?When I test with `http://תנאי קדם ודרישות הקורס.doc`,it will be invalid.

Comment: yes I'm checking it localy as it still under development, do try the url ""http://po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc" ans tell me if pass validation or not.

Comment: I test with `po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc`,and it is invalid.And you can see the picture in the end of my answer.

Comment: I saw but you didn't putted the http:// at beginning **"http://po:rt/תנאי קדם ודריש#ות הקורס.doc"**

Comment: It is still invalid.

Comment: any way i tired it again now and seems to work. thank you very much @yiyi-you

Comment: can you tell me what should i change in the regular expression pattern in order that he will accept '%20' in the url? lets say that I have a url like that "http://sub.example.com/root/a/b/c/d/somepage.aspx?%20https://www.example.com"